# How to properly intercept (hook) IME inputs in Windows 10?

Tags: c, .net, windows, hook

I tried to implement an automation tool, and got problem when intercepting IME (Windows 10's default Microsoft IME) input Unicode strings (such as Japanese/Chinese).

I've written a 64-bit dll for injection to other processes/windows. The dll is as follows,

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>

// for output only
static wchar_t* className(HWND hwnd) {
    static wchar_t className[128];
    ::GetClassNameW(hwnd, className, 128);
    return className;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK ImeCallback(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    std::wofstream out("test.log", std::ios::app);
    out.imbue(std::locale("zh_CN.UTF-8"));

    if (code >= 0)
    {
        PCWPSTRUCT msg = (PCWPSTRUCT)lParam;

        if (msg->message == WM_IME_COMPOSITION) {
            out << "composition: " << className(msg->hwnd) << ":";
            if (msg->lParam & GCS_COMPATTR) {
                out << ":GCS_COMPATTR";
            }
            if (msg->lParam & GCS_COMPCLAUSE) {
                out << ":GCS_COMPCLAUSE";
            }
            if (msg->lParam & GCS_COMPREADSTR) {
                out << ":GCS_COMPREADSTR";
            }
            if (msg->lParam & GCS_COMPREADATTR) {
                out << ":GCS_COMPREADATTR";
            }
            if (msg->lParam & GCS_COMPREADCLAUSE) {
                out << ":GCS_COMPREADCLAUSE";
            }
            if (msg->lParam & GCS_COMPSTR) {
                out << ":GCS_COMPSTR";
            }
            if (msg->lParam & GCS_CURSORPOS) {
                out << ":GCS_CURSORPOS";
            }
            if (msg->lParam & GCS_DELTASTART) {
                out << ":GCS_DELTASTART";
            }
            if (msg->lParam & GCS_RESULTCLAUSE) {
                out << ":GCS_RESULTCLAUSE";
            }
            if (msg->lParam & GCS_RESULTREADCLAUSE) {
                out << ":GCS_RESULTREADCLAUSE";
            }
            if (msg->lParam & GCS_RESULTREADSTR) {
                out << ":GCS_RESULTREADSTR";
            }
            if (msg->lParam & GCS_RESULTSTR) {
                out << ":GCS_RESULTSTR";
            }
            out << std::endl;
            if (msg->lParam & GCS_RESULTSTR) {
                wchar_t data[128] = { 0 };
                HIMC context = ImmGetContext(msg->hwnd);
                ImmGetCompositionStringW(context, GCS_RESULTSTR, data, 255);
                ImmReleaseContext(msg->hwnd, context);
                out << "  result data: " << data << std::endl;
            }
            else if (msg->lParam & GCS_COMPSTR) {
                wchar_t data[128] = { 0 };
                HIMC context = ImmGetContext(msg->hwnd);
                ImmGetCompositionStringW(context, GCS_COMPSTR, data, 255);
                ImmReleaseContext(msg->hwnd, context);
                out << "  composition data: " << data << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else if (msg->message == WM_IME_STARTCOMPOSITION) {
            out << "start composition" << std::endl;
        }
        else if (msg->message == WM_IME_ENDCOMPOSITION)
        {
            out << "end composition" << std::endl;
        }
        else if (msg->message == WM_IME_SETCONTEXT) {
            out << "set context : " << className(msg->hwnd) << ":" << (wParam ? "TRUE" : "FALSE") << std::endl;
            switch (msg->lParam) {
            case ISC_SHOWUICOMPOSITIONWINDOW:
                out << "  ISC_SHOWUICOMPOSITIONWINDOW" << std::endl;
                break;
            case ISC_SHOWUIGUIDELINE:
                out << "  ISC_SHOWUIGUIDELINE" << std::endl;
                break;
            case ISC_SHOWUIALLCANDIDATEWINDOW:
                out << "  ISC_SHOWUIALLCANDIDATEWINDOW" << std::endl;
                break;
            case ISC_SHOWUIALL:
                out << "  ISC_SHOWUIALL" << std::endl;
                break;
            case ISC_SHOWUICANDIDATEWINDOW:
                out << "  ISC_SHOWUICANDIDATEWINDOW" << std::endl;
                break;
            case ISC_SHOWUICANDIDATEWINDOW << 1:
                out << "  ISC_SHOWUICANDIDATEWINDOW << 1" << std::endl;
                break;
            case ISC_SHOWUICANDIDATEWINDOW << 2:
                out << "  ISC_SHOWUICANDIDATEWINDOW << 2" << std::endl;
                break;
            case ISC_SHOWUICANDIDATEWINDOW << 3:
                out << "  ISC_SHOWUICANDIDATEWINDOW << 3" << std::endl;
                break;
            default:
                out << "  default" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else if (msg->message == WM_IME_NOTIFY) {
            HIMC context;
            wchar_t data[128] = { 0 };

            out << "notify : " << className(msg->hwnd) << std::endl;
            switch (msg->wParam) {
            case IMN_CHANGECANDIDATE:
                out << "  IMN_CHANGECANDIDATE" << std::endl;
                break;
            case IMN_CLOSECANDIDATE:
                out << "  IMN_CLOSECANDIDATE" << std::endl;
                break;
            case IMN_CLOSESTATUSWINDOW:
                out << "  IMN_CLOSESTATUSWINDOW" << std::endl;
                break;
            case IMN_GUIDELINE:
                out << "  IMN_GUIDELINE" << std::endl;
                break;
            case IMN_OPENCANDIDATE:
                out << "  IMN_OPENCANDIDATE" << std::endl;
                break;
            case IMN_OPENSTATUSWINDOW:
                out << "  IMN_OPENSTATUSWINDOW" << std::endl;
                break;
            case IMN_SETCANDIDATEPOS:
                out << "  IMN_SETCANDIDATEPOS" << std::endl;
                break;
            case IMN_SETCOMPOSITIONFONT:
                out << "  IMN_SETCOMPOSITIONFONT" << std::endl;
                break;
            case IMN_SETCOMPOSITIONWINDOW:
                out << "  IMN_SETCOMPOSITIONWINDOW" << std::endl;
                break;
            case IMN_SETCONVERSIONMODE:
                out << "  IMN_SETCONVERSIONMODE" << std::endl;
                break;
            case IMN_SETOPENSTATUS:
                out << "  IMN_SETOPENSTATUS" << std::endl;
                break;
            case IMN_SETSENTENCEMODE:
                out << "  IMN_SETSENTENCEMODE" << std::endl;
                break;
            case IMN_SETSTATUSWINDOWPOS:
                out << "  IMN_SETSTATUSWINDOWPOS" << std::endl;
                break;
            default:
                out << "  default: " << msg->wParam << ":" << msg->lParam << std::endl;
                context = ImmGetContext(msg->hwnd);
                auto result = ImmGetCompositionStringW(context, GCS_RESULTSTR, data, 256);
                ImmReleaseContext(msg->hwnd, context);
                out << "  data: " << data << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else if (msg->message == WM_IME_CHAR) {
            out << "char:" << msg->wParam << std::endl;
        }
        else if (msg->message == WM_IME_CONTROL) {
            out << "control" << std::endl;
        }
        else if (msg->message == WM_IME_SELECT) {
            out << "select : " << className(msg->hwnd) << " : " << (msg->wParam ? "TRUE" : "FALSE") << " : " << msg->lParam << std::endl;
        }
        else if (msg->message == WM_IME_KEYDOWN) {
            out << "key down" << std::endl;
        }
        else if (msg->message == WM_IME_KEYUP) {
            out << "key up" << std::endl;
        }
        else if (msg->message == WM_IME_REQUEST) {
            out << "request" << std::endl;
        }

    }
    out.close();

    return ::CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

I then wrote a 64-bit .NET application to inject this dll.

```
public delegate long HookProc(long code, long wParam, long lParam);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadLibraryW", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpFileName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "FreeLibrary", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FreeLibrary([In] IntPtr hModule);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", BestFitMapping = false, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string procName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int hookType, HookProc hookFn, IntPtr hMod, int threadId);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int UnhookWindowsHookEx(int hookId);


public int hookId;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr hMod = LoadLibrary("ImeHook.dll");
    IntPtr callback = GetProcAddress(hMod, "ImeCallback");

    // 4 represents WH_CALLWNDPROC
    // Try to inject into all other 64-bits applications
    hookId = SetWindowsHookEx(4, (HookProc)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(callback, typeof(HookProc)), hMod, 0);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookId);
}
```

The program can indeed inject the DLL into other processes because I can see messages from various windows in the logging file.

I can even intercept the IME Unicode strings in the WM_IME_COMPOSITION message (GCS_RESULTSTR), but only for some applications such as 64-bit forms written by .NET.

For some other applications, such as Firefox and Microsoft Edge, I can only see some WM_IME_NOTIFY messages, and there are no any WM_IME_COMPOSITION/WM_IME_STARTCOMPOSITION/WM_IME_ENDCOMPOSITION messages received for these windows. Therefore I cannot get the final Unicode input strings for these windows.

Did I do something wrong? Is it even possible to get such information for all processes or windows (such as 64-bit Edge/Chrome/Firefox) in Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

- I also tried the method you described in this question but failed to capture the windows IME output Unicode string(Chinese)
- I found something from the Microsoft docs site, after windows XP, windows introduce the Text Services Framework, and the TSF manager functions as a mediator between an application and one or more text services, maybe there is no message like WM_IME_COMPOSITION or WM_CHAR sent by the IME for Firefox/Chrome/World in latest OS(windows 10 or 11)
- but when I use Notepad, still can get the Unicode string of Chinese by hook WH_CALLWNDPROC